# How do I generate a dataframe displaying the number of unique pairs between two vectors, for each unique value in one of the vectors?

Tags: r

First of all, I apologize for the title. I really don't know how to succinctly explain this issue in one sentence.

I have a dataframe where each row represents some aspect of a hospital visit by a patient. A single patient might have thousands of rows for dozens of hospital visits, and each hospital visit could account for several rows.

One column is Medical.Record.Number, which corresponds to Patient IDs, and the other is Patient.ID.Visit, which corresponds to an ID for an individual hospital visit. I am trying to calculate the number of hospital visits each each patient has had.

For example:

Medical.Record.Number    Patient.ID.Visit
AAAXXX           1111
AAAXXX           1112
AAAXXX           1113
AAAZZZ           1114
AAAZZZ           1114
AAABBB           1115
AAABBB           1116

would produce the following:

Medical.Record.Number   Number.Of.Visits
AAAXXX          3
AAAZZZ          1
AAABBB          2

The solution I am currently using is the following, where "data" is my dataframe:

```
#this function returns the number of unique hospital visits associated with the 
#supplied record number
countVisits <- function(record.number){
    visits.by.number <- data$Patient.ID.Visit[which(data$Medical.Record.Number  
                            == record.number)]

    return(length(unique(visits.by.number)))
}

recordNumbers <- unique(data$Medical.Record.Number)

visits <- integer()  
for (record in recordNumbers){
    visits <- c(visits, countVisits(record))
}
visit.counts <- data.frame(recordNumbers, visits)
```

This works, but it is pretty slow. I am dealing with potentially millions of rows of data, so I'd like something efficient. From what little I know about R, I know there's usually a faster way to do things without using a for-loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This essentially looks like a `table()` operation after you take out duplicates. First, some sample data

```
#sample data
dd<-read.table(text="Medical.Record.Number Patient.ID.Visit
AAAXXX 1111
AAAXXX 1112
AAAXXX 1113
AAAZZZ 1114
AAAZZZ 1114
AAABBB 1115
AAABBB 1116", header=T)
```

then you could do

```
tt <- table(Medical.Record.Number=unique(dd)$Medical.Record.Number)
as.data.frame(tt, responseName="Number.Of.Visits")  #to get a data.frame rather than named vector (table)

#   Medical.Record.Number Number.Of.Visits
# 1                AAABBB                2
# 2                AAAXXX                3
# 3                AAAZZZ                1
```

Or you could also think of this as an aggregation problem

```
aggregate(Patient.ID.Visit~Medical.Record.Number, dd, function(x) length(unique(x)))

#   Medical.Record.Number Patient.ID.Visit
# 1                AAABBB                2
# 2                AAAXXX                3
# 3                AAAZZZ                1
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, @MrFlick provided handful of perfectly valid approaches. Personally I'm fond of the `data.table` package. Its faster on large data frames and I find the logic to be more intuitive than the base functions.  I'd check it out if you are having problems with execution time.

```
library(data.table)
med.dt <- data.table(med_tbl)
num.visits.dt <- med.dt[ , num_visits = length(unique(Patient.ID.Visit)), 
                                          by = Medical.Record.Number]
```

`data.Table` should be much faster than `data.frame` on a large tables.